# Possible that 2,3 week old os is infected? rkhunter, chkrootkit

Tags: rkhunter, chkrootkit

Problem:
Rootkit checks...
Rootkits checked : 498
Possible rootkits: 5

```
/usr/bin/bsd-mailx                                       [ Warning ]
```

reinstalled, message keeps but now new: /usr/bin/lwp-request :: warning
Here::
Checking `lkm'...                                            OooPS, not expected 329818 value
chkproc: Warning: Possible LKM Trojan installed

doesn't detect any rootkit: rkhunter (but still says possible 5)
I don't like if a zero day is on my computer;
Also this here appears:

Checking for suspicious (large) shared memory segments   [ Warning ]

What's that???

I think that is all from the rootkit scanners...

clamav scanning now...  new: just 3 possible rootkits?? Is rkhunter a good software???!!!  This found by clamav (I tried to build a halium-boot for ubuntu touch) /home/france1/.fairphone3/halium/external/curl/lib/mk-ca-bundle.vbs: Sanesecurity.Malware.25834.JsHeur.UNOFFICIAL FOUND

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Is it personal machine or high-load server in the net?

Comment: Now my 20.10 (currently running) reports something (first scan), oh and this version is 21.04 @N0rbert

Comment: Apple Laptop (20.10) reports this: Searching for Linux.Xor.DDoS ...                            INFECTED: Possible Malicious Linux.Xor.DDoS installed.. rkhunter says command mail: warning

Comment: I've ubuntu desktop   .. appple laptop also says these:     /usr/bin/lwp-request                                     [ Warning ]
    /usr/bin/bsd-mailx                                       [ Warning ]

Comment: @france1 if you have additional information, please use the [edit] button to add it to your question, rather than posting it via comments

Comment: Why do you post the same question twice? It's better to keep the discussion in one place.

Comment: @Tilman: I do not understand you... I just posted that here...

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I mistook your answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1339811/671546 for a question.

Answer (score 0):

rkhunter is good software, but you have to know how to use it.

rkhunter looks for indicators of compromise (IOCs).
An IOC is not *proof* that you have been compromised but, as the name says, just an *indicator* that it may be so.
Consequently, if rkhunter emits a warning you should investigate that and, if it turns out that what it found is in in fact legitimate on your system, update your rkhunter policy so that it knows not to complain about that again.

As an example, rkhunter looks for certain types of shared memory segments that are known to be used by malware to hide itself. But there are also legitimate uses of that type of shared memory segments, for example in database software. So if you run rkhunter on a database server for the first time it will warn about those shared memory segments. You investigate and find that they are legitimately used by your database, you add a statement to that effect to your rkhunter policy, and rkhunter will not warn about them anymore.

Comment: I understand ..
But why else shows it first 5 possible and then 3 possible?? System didn't restart at all

Comment: The number alone is meaningless. IOCs may change over the system lifetime. Shared memory segments may be created or deleted, ports may be opened or closed, both legitimately or maliciously. The only sensible approach is to investigate the warnings individually and, if they turn out to be false positives, whitelist them in rkhunter.conf.